# tensorflow evaluate while training with queues?

Tags: python, queue, tensorflow

I preprocessed my data as tfrecord.   I feed my data by **queue** **instead of feed_dict.**

This is my code.

```
for i in range(100000000):
    sess.run(train_op)
    start_time = time.time()
    if i > 20 and i % 10 == 0:
        summaries_train = sess.run(Summaries)
        writer_train.add_summary(summaries_train, i)
        print("%dth batch took %fs, have scanned %d of %d" % (i, time.time()-start_time, i*cf.batch_size, all))
        print("loss: {0}, acc: {1}".format(sess.run(Loss), sess.run(Acc)))
```

My Question is: How can I evaluate while training?

When using queues, I don't have to write feed_dict. So How can I feed evaluating data to tensorflow ?

Comment: You could use a separate queue and a create a copy of your model that reads from that queue and reports accuracy

Comment: But in this way, I can only evaluate a batch. I want to evaluate the whole test dataset by feeding tensorflow some tfrecord files.

Comment: you can set `epochs=1` and keep running batches until you hit the end of data, adding up accuracies along the way

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like `eval_in_batches` function [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6431560b7ec3565154cb9cdc9c827db78ccfebe7/tensorflow/models/image/mnist/convolutional.py#L265) but where you take data from queue instead of `feed_dict`. Note that you will want to have a separate queue so that your evaluation doesn't take examples from training.

Another common pattern to evaluate while training is to start a separate CPU-only process which loads checkpoints and runs the evaluation continuously.

Comment: It's a bad idea to have two pipelines on the same graph. See [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!msg/discuss/mLrt5qc9_uU/sGNbC7GpAwAJ). Better practice is in the second point: run training and evaluation in separate processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate evaluation from training and even run it on a completely different machine/process. On your training machine (which has only training data) you periodically save your model to disk.

Your evaluation machine checks the folder with your models and once a new model appears it loads it and runs evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

All is the same as the training process except that you should 1) separate the training data and evaluation data; 2) don't run the optimization operation, aka gradient descent. I hope [this function](https://github.com/eduOS/abstractive_summarization/blob/c2c_w2c/gen_utils.py#L77) may be of help for you.